# jsoup table to get a particular element

Tags: java, jsoup

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(studentprofiles).get();
Element tables = doc.select("table");
Elements myTdsstudent = tables.select("tr td:eq(1)");
```

I am able to get all the details one after another in the eq(1).

In the example:

```
Table:    
GK   99    
NS   88    
PS   55
```

I have in HTML Table when I do eq(0) I get GK,NS,PS.
when I do eq(1) I get 99 88 55.

Is there a way so that I can read using JSOUP as

```
gk=99
ns=88
PS=55
```

Right now I am getting as 2 different array of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Elements myTdsstudent = tables.select("tr");
```

now iterate over `myTdsstudent` and use this

```
for (Element myTdsstudentIterator: myTdsstudent) {
    System.out.println(myTdsstudentIterator.select("td:eq(0)") + " = " + myTdsstudentIterator.select("td:eq(1)"));
}
```

Comment: Thankds Daniel for the reply.